# Shortest assignment of variables to DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a shorter way to assign multiple DOM elements to JS variables?

```
var searchButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');
var searchField = document.getElementById('searchField');
var usernameField = document.getElementById('usernameField');
var passwordField = document.getElementById('passwordField');
var goButton = document.getElementById('goButton');
```

Assuming I have many divs I would like to add\remove easily along the way.
The best would be to have an array I could just add\remove div ID's from and the rest is taken care of

Comment: use a function ...? how do you use the variables later?

Comment: Or you can use a loop and an array to store the references

Comment: @NinaScholz Made edits to the question

Comment: What's wrong with this code now? Why make it "shorter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over an array - this code assumes you really MUST have a global variable with the same name as the ID:

but [Avoid globals](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals)

```js
["searchButton", "usernameField"].forEach(id => window[id]=document.getElementById(id))


console.log(searchButton.innerText);
```

```html
<div id="usernameField">Username field</div>
<div id="searchButton">Search button</div>
```

HOWEVER that is already the case in many browsers although not recommended

```js
console.log(searchButton.innerText);
```

```html
<div id="usernameField">Username field</div>
<div id="searchButton">Search button</div>
```

Older answers based on initial information

Getting divs with IDs starting with "div"

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=div]")


console.log(divs[2].innerText); // 0 based
```

```html
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3">Div 3</div>
<div id="div4">Div 4</div>
```

If you want to make sure it ends with a number

```js
const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=div]")]
 .filter(div => /^div\d{1,2}$/.test(div.id))

console.log("Last div:",divs[divs.length-1].innerText)
```

```html
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3">Div 3</div>
<div id="div4">Div 4</div>

<hr/>

<div id="divIsUnrelated">Unrelated div</div>
```

If you must have a var for each

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=div]")].forEach(div => window[div.id] = div);

console.log(div3.innerText)
```

```html
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>
<div id="div3">Div 3</div>
<div id="div4">Div 4</div>
```

Comment: I need to create a var for each element

Comment: @Yigal Why? You could just access it via `divs[1]` etc.

Comment: @HaoWu Each div has its own name (eg. searchButton, usernameField etc.) and is manipulated later, it's not just numbers.

Comment: @Yigal That was important information, don't you think?

Comment: @mplungjan I do now

Comment: Why is it not recommended to assign global variables to elements?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals